# универсальные функции перекодировки строк ansi to unicode

Tags: c++, c++17

Есть такие функции перевода кодировок:

```
std::wstring str2wstr(std::string_view str)
{
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), nullptr, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}
std::string wstr2str(const std::wstring& wstr)
{
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr.c_str(), int(wstr.length() + 1), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    std::string strTo(size_needed, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr.c_str(), int(wstr.length() + 1), &strTo[0], size_needed, 0, 0);
    return strTo;
}
```

Не совсем подходит просит #include <windows.h>
Есть ли более универсальные аналоги. Благодарю за ответы!

Comment: Только наверное не ansi <-> unicode, а utf-8 <-> utf-16.

Comment: Библиотеки ICU, iconv

Comment: Посмотрите на "чистый c++" код преобразований. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16 Там примеры есть, но все зависит от стандарта, кое что введенное в C++11 уже объявлено устаревшим и планируется удалить в C++26 :)    А ваши функции, кстати, названы "неправильно" . По названию они взаимно обратимы, что не так. Вторая вообще зависит от установленной системной кодовой страницы windiows.

Comment: Если универсальность это windows/linux, то учтите, что в винде std::wstring это (в первом приближении!) utf-16, а в линуксе - utf-32.

Comment: Нашел простую библиотеку еще не проверял [http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net ]